# Use gdb with command file and arguments

Tags: bash, gdb, arguments

I am trying to create a script that will:

1. start gdb
2. set a substitute-path
3. attach to a process PID
4. set some breakpoints

After browsing the interent I created a script called 'gdbscript' that contains:

```
set substitue-path <from> <to>  
show substitute-path  
attach $1
```

I am calling this script by:

```
$ gdb -x gdbscript --args 4269
```

This is not working. Any ideea about how can I use a script with gdb and also pass arguments?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`$1` won't be enough, that's only the first argument `-x`.

What you need is `"$@"` which basically means all arguments, with preserved structure (not turning a single argument `"hello there"` into `hello` and `there`. The following transcript shows this in action:

```
pax> cat qq.sh
echo set substitue-path FROM TO
echo show substitute-path  
echo attach "$@"

pax> qq.sh -x gdbscript --args 4269 'hello there'
set substitue-path FROM TO
show substitute-path
attach -x gdbscript --args 4269 hello there
```

---

If, as you indicate in a comment, it's the *last* argument you want rather than them all, you can use `$BASH_ARGV`:

```
pax> cat qq.sh
echo set substitue-path FROM TO
echo show substitute-path  
echo attach $BASH_ARGV

pax> ./qq.sh -x gdbscript --args 4269
set substitue-path FROM TO
show substitute-path
attach 4269
```

Comment: My intention for attach is to have only 'attach 4269', so I need just the last argument.

Comment: @user3008084, that wasn't overly clear from your question but I've added some more detail to cover it.

Comment: sorry for not being explicit enough. Still, it is not working. I added in the script `attach $BASH_ARGV` and I am calling it like `gdb -x gdbscript --args 4269`. I get `gdbscript:3: Error in sourced command file:Illegal process-id: $BASH_ARGV.`